# Why does my Meteor.method return undefined?

Tags: meteor

There is a simple field to input a youtube ID. I am using renaldo's youtube api (https://atmospherejs.com/renaldo/youtube-api) to retrieve the title of the youtube clip.

The client side event passes the track ID (var tid) value to the method 'addTrack' successfully - it outputs the track's title to the console on the server. I am having a really bad time returning anything at all back to the client.

If I call the 'getVideoData' method from the 'addTrack' method, it still returns 'undefined' every time. I am no expert in meteor or javascript, this is just something I am learning for the hell of it.

I understand the concept of callbacks and the synchronous nature of javascript (I think!).

Thanks.

[EDIT The code below solves my problem, using Future]

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

  YoutubeApi.authenticate({
    type: 'key',
    key: API_KEY
  });

Meteor.methods({
  addTrack: function(tid) {

  Meteor.call("getVideoData", tid, function(err,res) {

    console.log(res);

    });
  },
  getVideoData: function(tid) {
    var future = new Future();

    YoutubeApi.videos.list({
    part: "snippet",
    id: tid,
  }, function (err,data) {
      var _data = {"title":data.items[0].snippet.title,"desc":data.items[0].snippet.description};
      future["return"](_data)

    });
    return future.wait();

}
```

Meteor.startup(function () {
    Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

});
}

Comment: This is a very common Meteor question that has several possible solutions. The basic issue is that your method is calling an asynchronous function.

Comment: How are you calling the method "getVideoData" from other methods, are you using Meteor.call("getVideoData")??

Comment: Yes, I am calling the method from another method via Meteor.call("getVideoData"), and still getting undefined.

Comment: Is the working code above the best way to achieve the asynchronous callback in Meteor 1.3?

Answer (score 2):

Meteor methods are tricky, as they use [Fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) to be synchronous (well, they appear to the developer as synchronous). So you need to use [Meteor.wrapAsync()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) to wrap the all to YoutubeApi. I haven't tested the following code, but it should look something like:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getVideoData: function(tid) {
    var syncYT = Meteor.wrapAsync(YoutubeApi.videos.list);
    var data = syncYT({part: "snippet",id: tid,});
    var transformed = {"title":data.items[0].snippet.title,"desc":data.items[0].snippet.description};

    console.log(transformed.title);
    return transformed.title;
  }
});
```

You'll want to read more about error handling in this case, but this should get you going. Just remember that client-side Meteor is always asynchronous and server-side is optionally asynchronous. Use wrapAsync or Futures to handle async needs in methods.

Lastly, the [Meteor guide](http://guide.meteor.com/methods.html) is great, use it!